# Audio performance issues after resuming from sleep/hibernate in Windows 10 build 10162

Tags: audio, performance, sleep, hibernate

I recently did a clean install of Windows 10 build 10162 from the official ISO provided to insiders, and I have discovered something with my audio performance that may or may not have been present before.

Whenever I resume from sleep or hibernate, everything appears to be fine except that any music sounds noticeably "slow" as I interact with the UI. This could mean dragging a window, scrolling in a webpage, or even just clicking on some UI element on screen. When this happens, I start to hear faint static, and the tempo of the audio slows down just a bit, as if to indicate high CPU usage. This always corrects itself after I do a full restart.

Sadly, there aren't many drivers available specifically for Windows 10, so I can't easily install new ones. I did install the latest Windows 10 driver for my Intel chipset, however, but that doesn't seem to have done anything. I suspect that it's not my audio driver because the problem persists even when I switch to listening through my USB headphones.

Has anybody run into this issue before? What might be the cause?

### System Specs:

- Processor: Intel 4770K
- Cooling: Corsair H80i
- Motherboard: ASUS Maximus VII Hero
- RAM: 32GB DDR3
- Video: 2x Sapphire R9 290
- OS Drive: 2x Samsung 840 EVO in RAID-0
- PSU: Corsair Professional HX850

Comment: nope - sounds exactly like your audio driver. Hope there are new ones on the horizon. btw, you didn't mention what the audio chip is or what drivers you currently have… might be useful...

Comment: I don't know exactly which chipset, but it's Realtek in any event. I don't see how that makes any sense though. I uninstalled the driver completely and used my USB headphones and still get the issue.

Comment: As odd as this sounds, it may have been my raid driver... Found this thread (http://www.sevenforums.com/sound-audio/95244-realtek-onboard-sound-card-static-crackling-noises.html) that suggested that this is what it might have been. I'll have to do further testing to make sure

Answer (score 0):

After finding a [similar sounding issue](http://www.sevenforums.com/sound-audio/95244-realtek-onboard-sound-card-static-crackling-noises.html) at sevenforums.com, it would appear that the cause of my issue is faulty RAID drivers from Intel. I installed an older version of Intel Rapid Storage Technology (along with the drivers) that I used on Windows 8.1, and the problem seems to have gone away.